# &amp; or &#38; what should be used for & (ampersand) if we are using UTF-8 in an XHTML document?

Tags: html, xhtml, html-entities

What is the difference between `&amp;` and `&#38;` for & (ampersand)?

What should be used with UTF-8?

Comment: And if you ever find yourself in Microsoft-land mixing up XML and normal code strings, sometimes you need to use `&&` for Labels and the like because nothing else will work **_shrug_**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both are [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) and refer to the same character (*AMPERSAND*, U+0026). `&amp;` is a named or entity character reference and `&#38;` is a numerical character reference.

In fact, `&amp;` is actually just a substitution for `&#38;` (see [list of character entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)):

> ```
> <!ENTITY amp     CDATA "&#38;"   -- ampersand, U+0026 ISOnum -->
> ```

Comment: ok thanks but what should be used with utf 8 "entity character reference" or "numerical character reference"?

Comment: @Jitendra: It doesn’t matter. You can use the form you want.

Comment: are both compatible with all browsing devices?

Comment: While they're equivalent, I'd favour use of `&amp;` as it's more readable.

Comment: For those that wonder if &#38 and U+0026 (or %26 in URL encoding) are related, 26 is hexadecimal for 38.

Answer (score 1):

If you both save your file in UTF-8 and even specify it for strict browsers:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
```

I would guess that you can also just use the & character.
All new browsers will support it and UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

*[Entities: Handling Special Content](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html)*

According to [O'Reilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Reilly_Media), you should be using & in XML. UTF-8 is quite a bit different. *[Unicode Character 'AMPERSAND' (U+0026)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0026/index.htm)*

Answer (score 0):

No difference. UTF-8 doesn't matter because & is reserved anyway. So use &amp;.