# What's the difference between %26 and &amp; for an ampersand?

Tags: html, url, escaping

I'm a little bit confused by the two representation of ampersand, `%26` and `&amp;`. For example, if I have a url like this: `www.example.com/?title=a&pic=b`, which one would achieve the same effect? `www.example.com/?title=a%26pic=b` or `www.example.com/?title=a&amp;pic=b`

Comment: basically different aliases to encode the character "&" ...

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141799/amp-or-38-what-should-be-used-for-ampersand-if-we-are-using-utf8-in-xht

Comment: @Mortalus Could you please name the different scenarios for these two forms? Thanks!

Comment: look at the question i posted at the comment above

Comment: Neither of those would achieve the same effect.  The ampersand in your example is part of the HTTP GET syntax, to separate the key/value pairs.  If you try to encode it, you will change the meaning of the URL.

Comment: @paddy So when could I use those two forms and when could I not?